# how to handle field in email of contact form 7 in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

IN my contact form 7 field are available in that some field are not mandatory. when i put blank this field in email label of field is included. (check below email format):

Name : bhavin

address : address1

phone no :

Email address : bsolanki.ce@gmail.com

...

Required format : when i dont enter value in phone no field at this time below email format send to email id

Name : bhavin

address : address1

Email address : bsolanki.ce@gmail.com

...

How it is possible..?

Comment: for this, I think you need to customize in contact form 7 plugin

Comment: @Khushboo : yes that i tryed. but still dont get any idea. where i have to change

Comment: I don't even understand the question, could you explain a little better?

Comment: yes,if you blank field in form which is not compulsory then it will not display in  mail body label as well null value

Comment: Try adding this code into functions.php: add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_components', 'remove_blank_lines' );

function remove_blank_lines( $mail ) {
 if ( is_array( $mail ) && ! empty( $mail['body'] ) )
  $mail['body'] = preg_replace( '|\n\s*\n|', "\n\n", $mail['body'] );

 return $mail;
}

Comment: This code is if the email is null.

Comment: No this id not my requirement, this used when whole body will null.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is running perfectly because if field not required then no value need to send email, here blank email will send to administrator on given mail id from backend.